# In Umbraco, how to repeat block of properties multiple times in document type?

Tags: umbraco

In Umbraco I have a document type (**A**) which I would like to contain **one or more** quizzes. A quiz contains these properties:

```
Quiz number
Quiz question
Quiz option #1
Quiz option #2
Quiz option #3
Quiz correct option
```

As I don't know beforehand how many quizzes there will be on the page, I figured I would move the quiz properties to a document type of it's own (**B**), and then  use that as a *composition* on **A**.

But it seems that using composition, I can only have one instance of **B**. How can I have the quiz repeated 1-n times as needed on **A**?

Comment: If you're on a newer (v7) Umbraco, use the Nested Content datatype - it helps you do exactly what you want, I think :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doc type B should not be a composition, it should be used for content nodes that are children of A.
You could also use Nested Content as Jannik suggests. Basically, you use B as your nested content doctype that can be repeated on your content node as many times as you like.